# How to check if a link is a download link using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, docker, url, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to get a link from a , and i wanted to check if it was a download link.

For that i used this code that i made with URL and URLConnection :

```
final WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pathToFile));
        URL url = null;
        final String urlFileToDownload = element.getAttribute("href");
        URLConnection myCon = null;
        String contentDisposition = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urlFileToDownload);
            myCon = url.openConnection();
            contentDisposition = myCon.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            if (!contentDisposition.contains("attachment;filename=")) {
                assertTrue(false, "The link isn't a download link.");
            }
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new TestIntegrationException("Error while creating URL : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new TestIntegrationException("Error while connecting to the URL : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        assertTrue(true, "Link is a download link.");
```

The probleme is that my link is a download link as you can see on this picture : [Image-link-download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qFG.png). (the picture is a print-screen of the console)
And when i open the connection of `url.openConnection();`

`myCon.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition")` is null.

I've searched a way to do this but everytime my header-field is empty and i can't find the problem because when i check with the console, my headerfield isn't empty ...

EDIT : I'm launching my selenium test on a docker server, i think that's a important point to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by my session who was different with the `url.openConnection()`.

To correct the problem i've collected my cookie JSESSION using selenium like that :

```
String cookieTarget = null;
    for (final Cookie cookie : this.kSupTestCase.getDriver().manage().getCookies()) {
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(cookie.getName(), "JSESSIONID")) {
            cookieTarget = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Then i've put the cookie to the opened connection :

```
try {
        url = new URL(urlFichierATelecharger);
        myCon = url.openConnection();
        myCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieCible);
        contentDisposition = myCon.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        if (!contentDisposition.contains("attachment;filename=")) {
            assertTrue(false, "The link isn't a download link.");
        }
    } catch [...]
```

Like that i've got the good session and my URL was recognized as a download link.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/64qFG.png");

WebElement img = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/img")));
Dimension h = img.getSize();
Assert.assertNotEquals(0, h);
```

Comment: The image that i've shared isn't the link i try to test, it's a link that show the console from chrome of my link when i launch a download like java do when i openConnection().

Comment: I get it, just used the image as target file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for attachments why don't you look at the MIME type?

```
String contentType = myCon.getContentType();

if(contentType.startsWith("text/")) {
    assertTrue("The link isn't a download link.", false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still return a null element. My function works when i try with other link so i think the problem isn't in the function but with selenium or docker.

Comment: Is it possible the link isn't really a link but JavaScript meant to look like a link?  So it doesn't actually point to anything but instead starts a dynamic stream.

Comment: I've found the solution to the problem, you can see it below. The problem was caused by the session launched with openConnection() whose not the session running on selenium.